# Locally installed webdriver-manager(through protractor) update issue : E/downloader - undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, protractor, webdriver-manager

**Setup :**  node.js V6.11.0 , npm V5.0.3 , protractor V5.1.2 (installed locally at project root)

```
proxy setting using environemnt variable  :
proxy=http://my-proxy.com:8080
https_proxy=http://my-proxy.com:8080
no_proxy=localhost;github.com
```

**when i try to run :**
`C:\Users\username\Desktop\localrepo\my-projectst\node_modules\.bin>webdriver-manager update`     (no global installation at this moment)

**I get :**

> [10:18:45] I/file_manager - creating folder
>   C:\Users\username\Desktop\localrepo\my-projectst\node_m
>   odules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium
>   **[10:18:51] E/downloader - undefined** [10:18:51] I/update - geckodriver: file exists
>   C:\Users\username\Desktop\localrepo\my-projectst\nod
>   e_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\geckodriver-v0.17.0.zip
>   [10:18:51] I/update - geckodriver: unzipping geckodriver-v0.17.0.zip
>   **(node:15188) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Invali d filename** [10:19:02] I/update -
>   chromedriver: unzipping chromedriver_2.30.zip

**Works fine :**

**1.** `C:\Users\username\Desktop\localrepo\my-projectst\node_modules\.bin>webdriver-manager start`

**2.** Global protractor installation and then webdriver-manager update works completely fine .

Can someone point out whats the issue or guide me to correct approach

Answer (score 0):

You can try a cleaner approach of uninstalling the current version and then install protractor again locally using the following command:
 npm install protractor --save-dev

Go to the bin folder where webdriver-manager is located and update(if required) and start accordingly
cd ../node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update

Comment: Not sure if you are using the correct form, your command and path inside node_modules should look like this :                                                        
node C:\Users\username\Desktop\localrepo\my-projectst\node_modules\protractor\bin\webdriver-manager update